# Should I choose 26" or 28" size BTWIN Triban 100 with dropped handlebar?

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, size

My height is 5 ft 9.5" (176.5 cm). I went to Decathlon and tried out both the 26" and 28" bicycles there. Both sizes felt comfortable. But I cannot really tell unless I ride for a long distance. I had to raise the seat of the 26" and had to very slightly decrease the seat height of the 28".

Which bicycle size should I choose?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that both "26" and "28" are frame sizes, not wheel sizes? I am asking because these particular values often correspond to two popular wheel sizes, and I was confused for a while. Please edit your question to clarify this point for other readers.

Comment: Apparently this bike is made with both "26 inch" and "28 inch" wheels. The smaller version is supposedly for children and very short adults. 176cm is certainly adult sized. And yes, one should look at frame, not wheel sizes. The need to adjust seat height is normal and doesn't tell anything.

Comment: seriously i don't know the exact sizes, I'm pretty new to this. There were just two sizes M and L. The only difference between the two was that L was 5cm higher than M. I'm from india and i'm pretty sure that unless your into professional biking you aren't gonna have an option of frame sizes

Comment: If you think the size doesn't matter, why do you ask?

Comment: for the sake of my uncertainty

Comment: Are you still growing?  If you're under 20 take the larger bike because of growth.  I asked because your height has increased an inch in the month between your two postings.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical height is easier to adjust than 'reach' or the horizontal distance from the handle bar. Check which one is more comfortable there. I would err on the smaller size myself, as long as it isn't too small, since the reach being even slightly longer causes neck and other pains.

Answer (score 0):

So far 700 kms using Triban 100 (L size), I'm 175 cms.
I feel L is good..

Though store helper suggested me M size, i chose L.. and feeling it's a good choice. Meanwhile i also tried M in the store after few hundreds on L.. and confirmed L is the perfect choice.

And mine it's straight bar..

Comment: So the standard advise "ride the bike you personally find comfortable" holds true.